# `&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

I saw the code from [here](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/)

```
Post.published.collect(&:views_count)
```

I guess it equals to

```
.collect { |p| p.views_count }
```

But I never saw this usage before, does this have a name? Where can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a rather clever hack made it into ruby 1.9.

Basically, `&` in front of a variable in ruby coerces it into a proc. It does that by calling `to_proc`. Some clever fellow (first time I saw this was in _whys code, but I won't credit him cause I don't know if he came up with it) added a `to_proc` method to `Symbol`, that is essentially `{|obj| obj.send self}`.

There aren't many coercians in ruby, but it seems like all of them are mostly used to do hacks like this (like !! to coerce any type into a boolean)

Comment: Since the code snippet in question is using rails, it should be pointed out that `Symbol#to_proc` was in Active Support long before ruby 1.9, so you can use it in rails code without worrying about compatibility with ruby version.

Answer (score 2):

It's a use of `Symbol#to_proc`. The `&` operator turns a Proc object into a block, and because Ruby 1.8.7 and newer implement `Symbol#to_proc`, it can be used with a symbol like `:views_count`. And yes, it's equivalent to `{|p| p.views_count}`.